# Nvidia plugin for Conky

Tags: nvidia, conky

I want to display GPU speed, Memory, and Temperature on my conky configuration. On the conky [site](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html) it says you can use `${nvidia temp}°C` to show it. However, when this happens, it takes it as litteral text. I've read a bit, and it looks like I'm missing a plugin or something. Some sources say to install Nvidia-Settings which I've already had installed. (PS i have a gefore 360m)

I was able to get a temp reading as you can see in the top of this picture. I used a long line of code `${execi 60 nvidia-settings -query GPUCoreTemp | perl -ne 'print $1 if /GPUCoreTemp.*?: (\d+)./;'} °C` But the conky objects are much cleaner, and I'd like to just be able to use them instead.

Does anyone know how I can get this working? (See VIDEO section)

Here's the code for the Video section...

`${font Arial:bold:size=10}${color White}VIDEO ${color DarkSlateGray}${hr 2}

$font${color DimGray}NVidia GeForce 360m GPU $alignr${nvidia gpufreq}Mhz

Memory $alignr${nvidia memfreq}Mhz Temperature $alignr${nvidia temp}Mhz`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
${color CC9900}GPU:$color $alignr ${execi 60 nvidia-settings -query GPUCoreTemp | perl -ne 'print $1 if /GPUCoreTemp.*?: (\d+)./;'} C
${color CC9900}VIDEO ${hr 2}$color
NVidia GeForce GPU $alignr ${nvidia gpufreq} Mhz
Memory $alignr ${nvidia memfreq} Mhz
Temperature $alignr ${nvidia temp} C
```

Comment: It works for me without the `$alignr` code.

Comment: I think you should write `${alignr}` instead `$alignr`

Answer (score 10):

In the terminal run `conky -v`
If you don't see nvidia in the compiled in features, install the **conky-all** package which is compiled with all options including nvidia.

Comment: For me in addition to installing conky-all I also needed to ensure the  proprietary drivers were active.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to use the nvidia-settings application, conky can read the values itself. You just have to recompile conky with the `--enable-nvidia` option. Then `${nvidia temp}°C` will work. It's not compiled by default because of known reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
${color CC9900}GPU:$color $alignr ${execi 60 nvidia-settings -query GPUCoreTemp | perl -ne 'print $1 if /GPUCoreTemp.*?: (\d)./;'} C
${color CC9900}VIDEO ${hr 2}$color
NVidia GeForce GPU $alignr ${nvidia gpufreq} Mhz
Memory $alignr ${nvidia memfreq} Mhz
Temperature $alignr ${nvidia temp} C
```

in the original answer the line .../GPUCoreTemp.*?: (\d)./;'} C... had a + symbol to the right of the \d which caused the temperature to be listed twice.


Example: 43 C = 4343 C


I just thought I would put this up in case anyone else came across this post.

Answer (score 0):

I use `nvidia-smi`. The Nvidia part in my `conky` is:

```
${color FFA300}GPU:$color${font}${exec nvidia-smi -L | cut -c 6-30}${color FFA300} Freq:$color${nvidia gpufreq} Mhz $color${color FFA300}Temperature $color${nvidia temp} C
${color FFA300}Watt:$color${font}${exec nvidia-smi -i 0 -q -d POWER |grep "Draw" | cut -c 45-49}${color FFA300} Used:$color${font}${exec nvidia-smi -i 0 -q -d MEMORY |grep "Used" | cut -c 45-55 | head -1 
}
```