# Ubuntu 16.04 apt-get doesn't provide conky-all from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, package-management, downgrade, conky

When upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 my Conky scripts were automatically converted from Conky 1.9 format to new Conky 1.10 format but they were broken and won't run under Conky 1.10. So I downgraded Conky from 1.10 to 1.9 which Ubuntu 14.04 uses.

However I only downgraded `conky-std` and not `conky-all`. Now I want to get nvidia-settings GPU Mhz, Memory Mhz, Memory usage and Temperature statistics in Conky and the easiest method is with `conky-all`: [askubuntu...nvidia-plugin-for-conky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147283/nvidia-plugin-for-conky)

When I try to install older 14.04 version with:

```
sudo apt-get install conky-all=1.9.0-4
```

as instructed in: [askubuntu...how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get), I get the bad news:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.9.0-4' for 'conky-all' was not found
```

This didn't happen a few weeks ago when I purged `conky-all 1.10.1-3` and installed `conky-std 1.9.0-4` and froze it.

On the page: [ubuntu.com/trusty/conky-all](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/conky-all) under Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) the `conky-all 1.9.0-4` version exists and relevant documentation is all there so it's not as if support for Trusty package is gone.

`apt-cache policy conky-all` reveals:

```
conky-all:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.10.1-3
  Version table:
     1.10.1-3 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

`apt-cache policy conky-std` reveals:

```
conky-std:
  Installed: 1.9.0-4
  Candidate: 1.10.1-3
  Version table:
     1.10.1-3 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 1.9.0-4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

1. Should I manually go about installing it outside of apt-get?
2. Should I link to a different PPA and apt-get that way?
3. Are the Ubuntu packages temporarily broken and only showing `conky-all` version 1.10 today and will be fixed tomorrow? (yeah wishful thinking of a procrastinator).

Thanks to any conky experts that may be watching out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is fairly straightforward to use the older version under Xenial and a big 'thanks' to Cory Goldberg for this information. I have modified Cory's method in quite a few places:

1. Remove any existing version of conky:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge conky-std conky-all
   ```
2. Download the older version of the `conky-all` package:

   ```
   wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/conky/conky-all_1.9.0-6build1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Install with gdebi:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdebi
   sudo gdebi conky-all_1.9.0-6build1_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Lock or pin your older version to prevent the Repository installing the newer version next time you update:

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold conky-all
   ```

And then enjoy your older version of conky :)

Below is a screenshot of the 'pinned' older version of Conky on Xenial, seen in my old friend Synaptic, the exclamation mark signifying that the package is 'pinned':

[image]

**References:**

- [Cory Goldberg: What The Heck Happened To Conky? (I'm rolling back to 1.9)](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com.au/2016/03/what-heck-happened-to-conky-im-rolling-back.html)

Comment: @Andrew46 Thanks a bunch. I actually used Cory Goldberg's blog to install conky-std 1.9.0-4 in the first place. Too bad I was too blind to see how to apply that with conky-all like you have. Now my Conky monitor Nvidia stats no longer say "Nvidia" they say "N/A" so progress is made!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Good to hear it all worked! Yes, just a little bit of editing to Cory's work to get what you were after. And have a great day :)