# Conky problem indicator

Tags: conky

I installed `conky manager` on my desktop and my laptop but many conky indicators are not loading fine.

My PC has good performance but indicator lines and images don't show up and fail. Why?

[image: Screenshot here]

I've solved my problem but I still have error.

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Did it work in a previous version?

Comment: im using ubuntu 16.04 lts im searching 3 weaks on youtube ubuntu (persian-english)froums for this problem , my iranian friend told me to inestall lua for shown circle and images(my problem solved) but some indicators not loading, not showing good im thinking web servers are indicators using for temp and weather are blocked in iran :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can downgrade Conky to version 1.9. When Ubuntu 16.04 is installed a newer Conky version 1.10 was installed and it broke a lot of scripts for many people (including me).

To see which Conky Version you are running type: `conky -v`.

If you are on 1.10 you follow the answer in this question: [Ubuntu 16.04 apt-get doesn't provide conky-all from Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824617/ubuntu-16-04-apt-get-doesnt-provide-conky-all-from-ubuntu-14-04) to install 1.9 `conky-all`.

I doubt Iran is blocking weather websites. They'll probably take a track like Russia of targeting foreign NGO's instead. After all Iran let you into this website and you get to talk to us :)

Comment: I won't have time to test it until tonight but the conky-cli package (version 1.9.0-6  for debian is described and downloadable at: [https://packages.debian.org/jessie/utils/conky-cli].

Comment: im downgrade to 1.9.0.6 and finally all my problem solved thabk u very much dear :x

Comment: @Nima it was my pleasure to help out. Could you point out how my answer can be improved and then check it off as solution and up-vote it so others in the same situation can rely on it to help them too?

Comment: when conky 1.10 install on my ubuntu the circle, images not show all of indicator missing and not loadin so i should install lua the circles shown However the problem still persists:( im downgrade conky to 19.0.6 using ur Guidance(and install conky manager with this) and without install lua this time all of indicators shown very good ,work fine without any problem in terminall thank u very much for Saved me from wandering im very happy

Comment: no because my reputation less than 15 when its gain im click on up arrow