# Gnome system monitor applet for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

Is anyone aware of a system monitor panel applet for Gnome in Ubuntu 16.04?

I had been using [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) for years, but it no longer works in 16.04.

The only one capatible with 16.04 is [this one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1064/system-monitor/), but it doesn't actually display resource usage. It only displays links to make an overlay popup that shows resource usage.

Comment: If you are using Conky as a system monitor it breaks in 16.04 but it can be fixed. See this answer: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/831946/conky-problem-indicator/832256#832256]

Comment: try indicator-multiload