# Is there some way that I can see performance in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, performance

I am a new Linux user. In Windows, I used to monitor and sometimes improve my performance by using a software called "Advanced Systemcare". Is there some kind of software like this for Ubuntu? or someway that I can monitor how the things are going?

Thank You!

Comment: BTW, Advanced SystemCare is arguably junk. MalwareBytes Anti-Malware flags it as a "potentially unwanted program" (PUP). I would recommend CCleaner instead for Windows.

Comment: I might add to @wjandrea comment that ***Advanced SystemCare*** is a free program: http://download.cnet.com/Advanced-SystemCare-Free/3000-2086_4-10407614.html and as such they *might* make their profits from the malware embedded in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows architecture is built around a central database called "the Registry" which overtime as programs are added and deleted becomes insanely large and the system bogs down. As such every few years many users find deleting Windows and reinstalling it along with all currently used programs makes things seem 2 to 10 times faster.

Within Linux there is no Registry, and such performance penalties aren't suffered. Hence there is no need for a program like IObit Advanced Systemcare.

If your web browser slows down in Windows or in Linux (or Mac for that matter) because of too many extensions, Google and Firefox have methods of dealing with that differently.

The annoying malware pop-ups you find in Windows web browsers do not seem to occur (to me at least) with Linux web browsers. Free programs you download in Windows often come with embedded pop-up advertising malware that slows down your system. In Ubuntu almost everything is free and  designed to be downloaded via `sudo apt-get install`, instead of via the web browser.

Like any other system, if you have limited RAM, buying more RAM will speed up Linux. Also if you have an HDD (hard disk drive), spending $100+ on an SSD (solid state dive) will speed things up tremendously.

---

Your question body is primarily about speeding up the system however your question title is about monitoring system performance. To monitory the system I personally like to use `conky` but other people have their own preferences.

Here is what my Conky display looks like:

[image: ConkyCPU.gif]

When the image first starts you see what operation looks like under low load. The CPU's have low percentage utilization ~6%. The CPU speed is low ~1300 Mhz.

After opening Google Chrome (with 10 tabs) CPU utilization spikes up across all 8 CPUs to ~40% and the CPU speed jumps to maximum of 3400 Mhz.

Below the CPU information the names of the 10 top CPU consuming programs (processes) appear on my Conky display. Below that are displayed the amount of RAM used (26%) and amount of disk space (really an SSD) used (73%). Below that (but cut off from this picture) it shows the amount of ISP gigabytes consumed for the month. This helps prevent over billing.

If you would like to learn more about Conky I recommend this site: [Post your .conkyrc files w/ screenshots](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865)

If you are looking for off-the-shelf system performance monitoring tools in general here is one thread: [What can replace system monitoring in the top Gnome Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity/35733#35733)

You will find other system monitoring tools recommended in Ask Ubuntu if you do a search.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have installed conky, but, when I open it, makes my entire desktop blinks , I don't now if it is because the version tha I'm using or anyway, any sulution? But thank you anyway.

Comment: @BrunoNavarro Conky is a powerful tool and as such requires much experimentation (sometimes weeks of time) to get it right. When Ubuntu 16.04 came out I had problems and had to downgrade to Conky  version that comes with Ubuntu 14.04. Those instructions can be found here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/831946/conky-problem-indicator/832256#832256 Others are using the new Conky without problems and can probably support you better than I on that version. In the meantime try the "simple" performance monitors on my second link. That will get you started in a few minutes.

Comment: @BrunoNavarro I just checked out the answers in the duplicate close vote. There are some really good solutions there for a beginner like yourself. After you gain experience in Linux you can install and learn Conky.

Answer (score 2):

I designed and built many of the large NOCs in the Pacific Northwest so monitoring is a topic that is near and dear to my heart.

At a user level, you can open something like System Monitor which is part of the standard Ubuntu distribution.  It is very similar to the task manager in the Microsoft world.

I also always have two terminal sessions open.  One running

```
nice top
```

and one running

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

You will have to restart the tail once a day when the log files get rolled.

There are a few other log files that you may find interesting depending on how paranoid you are about security.  But since your focus seems to be on performance, those three "monitors" should more than satisfy your needs.

You may also want to run Bleachbit now and then just to keep things cleaned up.  I run it right after a reboot.  Once as root (sudo) and once under my mortal user login.  Bleachbit is similar to Ccleaner in the Microsoft world.

I listed top and tailing syslog because that methodology will be available on pretty much any *NIX system you will ever use.  I've been running top and tailing syslog for at least 30 years.  It rarely takens me very long to notice when something goes awry.  Bleachbit, on the other hand, is free, easy to use, easy to install and is the tool of choice for many professional IT organizations.

Comment: BleachBit is *way overkill* on Linux, though, and should not be recommended because it can do more harm than good especially in the hands of new or less experienced users

Answer (score 0):

My all-time favorite process and CPU load viewer is **htop**. Significantly better, more user friendly,  and more powerful than *top*. It can be installed via Synaptic or via apt-get. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/linux-htop-examples/  Once you are used to htop, you’ll never go back to top again.

Answer (score -1):

The ubuntu command "top" is a dynamic real time view of the running tasks and system.  It can sort by CPU or memory

Comment: `top` isn't really a Ubuntu command, it's more of a Linux command. In any respect you could improve your answer with a screen shot and brief summary of keys that control the program.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's arguably not specifically a Linux command either ;)